# changing image repository from Container Registry to Artifact Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

With GCP's announcement of deprecating Container Registry, I am trying to migrate my CR images to Artifact Registry.

While GCP provides a [detailed guide](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr?authuser=1) on this migration, all of my images are for Cloud Functions. I was wondering if instead of following the guide, I could just simply switch the setting for the Cloud Function.

I have already tested that changing this setting creates a folder inside Artifact Registry for each Cloud Function.

Will this have any negative side effects that I am not aware of?

[image]

Comment: There is no impact, no change, same cost. You simple have more features with Artifact Registry!

Comment: Thank you! So I understand that if all my images in Container Registry are for Cloud Functions only, the migration is as simple as changing the setting on Cloud Functions. Nice